# How to fix "not a valid AllXsd value" in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services

I am trying to consume a web service by passing in a date time however I am getting the following:

The string '5/19/2010 5:25:21 PM' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Do I need to convert the string "5/19/2010 5:25:21 PM" to a meaningful object in objective C and if so how?

Comment: How are you getting this error? Is there a crash log?

Comment: The application is not crashing. This is a standard NSLog of the web service response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you seem to be sending the date in the wrong format. You need to send this in `2008-02-16T18:13:00` format. You can get that using a date formatter using,

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSString * theDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"%@", theDateString);
```

Use this when you are building the request.