# Datetime error occur in soap php

Tags: php, soap

I am now create redbus api using soap method in php.

now my coding having some datetime problem. these are the code

```
$c = new soapclient('...wsdl....',
 array('Authentication' => array('LoginID' =>'x','Password'=>'x')));

$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
 $time='2012-04-17T16:50:45';
$date = new DateTime($time,$timezone);
$sourceid=array('SourceID'=>'244','DestinationID'=>'477','DateOfJourney' =>$date);
```

it shows error as 
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 252). ---> The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value

I this should be Date problem

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448642/how-to-fix-not-a-valid-allxsd-value-in-objective-c

Comment: thanks for your advice but i need the code it in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you need it in PHP, here it is:

Replace

```
$sourceid=array('SourceID'=>'244','DestinationID'=>'477','DateOfJourney' =>$date);
```

with

```
$sourceid=array('SourceID'=>'244','DestinationID'=>'477','DateOfJourney' =>str_replace($date->format( 'P' ), '', $date->format( 'c' )));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not working it shows error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: <?php
$c = new soapclient('http://www.redbus.in/WS2/BookingService.asmx?wsdl', array('Authentication' => array('LoginID' => 'x','Password'=>'x')));
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
 $time='2012-04-17T16:50:45';
$date = new DateTime($time,$timezone);
$sourceid=array('SourceID'=>'244','DestinationID'=>'477','DateOfJourney' =>str_replace($date->format( 'P' ), '', $date->format( 'c' )));
$stockprice = $c->GetAvailableRoutes($sourceid);
print_r($stockprint);
?>